# Can I reference an external DTD for the structure of an ELEMENT in a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

Can I define a DTD such that elements in it have their structures defined in an external DTD?
I mean something like the following (this is an example that I know is invalid in several ways, but which hopefully will give you an idea of what I am looking for):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY % MessageHdr-DTD SYSTEM "./messagehdr.dtd">
<!ENTITY % MessageBody-DTD SYSTEM "./messagebody.dtd">
<!ELEMENT Message (MessageHdr, MessageBody)>
<!ELEMENT MessageHdr (MessageHdr-DTD)>
<!ELEMENT MessageBody (MessageBody-DTD)>
```

The attempt here is to represent that a Message requires a MessageHdr and a MessageBody, but that those two elements are defined in externally referenced DTDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and you are very close with your example. You just need to reference the [parameter entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-PE). Here's an example of 3 DTD's and an XML instance. I only used `#PCDATA` for `MessageHdr` and `MessageBody`, but this can be any structure you define.

**message.dtd**

```
<!ENTITY % MessageHdr-DTD SYSTEM "./messagehdr.dtd">
<!ENTITY % MessageBody-DTD SYSTEM "./messagebody.dtd">
%MessageHdr-DTD;
%MessageBody-DTD;
<!ELEMENT Message (MessageHdr, MessageBody)>
```

**messagehdr.dtd**

```
<!ELEMENT MessageHdr (#PCDATA)>
```

**messagebody.dtd**

```
<!ELEMENT MessageBody (#PCDATA)>
```

**message.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE Message SYSTEM "message.dtd">
<Message>
  <MessageHdr>header info</MessageHdr>
  <MessageBody>body info</MessageBody>
</Message>
```

Comment: Excellent... exactly the answer I was looking for. I tried it and it validates perfectly. Thanks.