# Including a DTD in another DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Is it possible to include a DTD in another DTD?  (I don't mean copy-and-paste the second DTD into the first DTD.  I mean to have something like a pointer to the second DTD in the first DTD.)

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259366/can-i-reference-an-external-dtd-for-the-structure-of-an-element-in-a-dtd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. One way is to use [*parameter entity*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-PE), which can be used within the DTD. Let's look at example:

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "first.dtd" [
    <!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)> <!-- you can also add DTD here -->
]>
<note>
    <type>business</type>
    <to>George W.</to>
    <from>Me</from>
    <heading>meeting</heading>
    <body>Meet me in central park at 16</body>
</note>
```

**First (referencing) DTD:**

```
<!ELEMENT note (type,to,from,heading,body)>
<!ENTITY % elements SYSTEM "second.dtd">
%elements;
```

**Second (referenced) DTD:**

```
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
```

As checked with Oxygen XML you can even make third DTD, which is referenced from second and so on. However you can't use recursive entity references e.g.:

elements1.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY % elements2 SYSTEM "elements2.dtd">
%elements2;
```

elements2.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY % elements1 SYSTEM "elements1.dtd">
%elements1;
```

> [Xerces] Recursive entity reference
>   "%elements1". (Reference path:
>   %elements1 -> %elements2 ->
>   %elements1),